# Single word/ phrase for "a problem that can be solved right way/easily"

Tags: phrases, single-word

My sentence is:

**A is not a problem that can be solved easily.**

I need a single word/ a phrase (adjective + noun) to replace "a problem that can be solved easily". I would prefer a formal word/phrase which is suitable for formal essays.

Comment: *It's a [**thorny** problem.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+a+thorny+problem&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20thorny%20problem%3B%2Cc0) In most formal contexts it's probably better to say *X is **problematic*** rather than *X is a **____** problem*.

Comment: Or just **A is a difficult problem**

Answer (score 1):

Try "A is not a trivial problem" (or also, as suggested by @PeterJennings, "A is a non-trivial problem").

Comment: I've often seen this version as **A is a non-trivial problem**

Comment: @PeterJennings Yes, this might be even better, thanks.

Comment: Even more formal sounding: *not a trivial/a non-trivial **matter***